How to change shapes and traits of horizontal lines in headers/footers?
I was just browsing through this site, searching for ways to change the shapes of horizontal lines in headers/footers out of curiosity, but I could only find questions relating to changing their color. I know changing the shapes can probably be done through the fancyhdr package by redefining \headruleand \footrule, but I don't know how, and I think others could benefit from/also be interested in learning ways to accomplish this goal. Here's some inspiration for what ways one could perhaps be interested in having their lines look like:
Only bottom 3 are of interest for the 1st picture



I'd personally prefer the solutions to be provided using the fancyhdr package, but whatever solution can achieve the goal of having beautiful/unique shapes for the horizontal lines should be posted for the greatest benefit.
Remember to also show the produced output of your code - Thank you in advance!
Edit 1:
Upon suggestion in the comments I've chosen to update the post with the typical packages I use in my document and the class:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}


Remember to also show a small, but compilable test document so we can see which class you use. Some classes have their own mechanism for headlines.

Ah, okay. I typically use the article class because I'm at my first year of university, but I could imagine we'd switch over to report for longer assignments in the coming years. Should I also include one for report, or do the commands work identically for article and report?

NOTE: This only works for page styles defined with fancyhdr.
If you just want to change the thickness, redefine \headrulewidth. For example:
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}

TeX doesn't have the concept of pixels, so you can't use 1px or 0.5px. You will have to know the dpi and then recalculate it to pt, mm, in or the like.
If you want colors or other shapes, redefine \headrule, e.g.,
\newbox\dashbox\setbox\dashbox\hbox{-\,}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\makebox[\headwidth][c]{\xleaders\copy\dashbox\hfill}}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{blue}\rule{\headwidth}{2.5pt}}


\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\setlength\headheight{14.4pt}

\renewcommand\headrule{\vspace{-6pt}\hrulefill
 \raisebox{-2.1pt}
   {\quad\decofourleft\decotwo\decofourright\quad}\hrulefill}


For more complicated things like gradients, use tikz inside the \headrule definition. For example:
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
  \tikz \fill [left color=green,right color=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (\headwidth,2.5pt);
}


For the footer these would be \footrulewidth and \footrule

Amazing stuff, thank you for setting the first example! Is it right to assume that in order to make some of the horizontal lines in the 2nd picture or a gradient like in the 1st one, you should define commands regarding these using tikz and then somehow find a way to make them compatible with headers and footers?

Instead of \color{blue}\rule{\headwidth}{2.5pt} use a tikz picture of width \headwidth and height whatever you want (e.g. 2.5pt).

I added an example with tikz.

Nicee, are you thinking of gradually expanding upon this answer of yours the more of the examples you figure out? That'd also be very much appreciated!:)

I might add a section to the fancyhdr manual with a selection of these.

That'd be greatly appreciated if you could do that sometime! Do keep me posted on the progress!
